# Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $\textbf{R}_{+}$ be the set of positive real numbers.

The following is a well-known theorem due to Euler:

*A differentiable function $f:\textbf{R}^n_{+} \rightarrow \textbf{R}_{+}$ is positively homogeneous ($f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for all $\lambda > 0$) if and only if $x \cdot \nabla f(x)=f(x)$.*

I am trying to prove a slightly stronger result:

*A locally Lipschitz function $f:\textbf{R}^n_{+} \rightarrow \textbf{R}_{+}$ is positively homogeneous iff $x \cdot \nabla f(x) = f(x)$ holds for almost all $x$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.* (Note: by Rademacher's theorem, the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ exists a.e.).

An attempt of proof (please, check!).

$\Rightarrow$ Differentiating the identity $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ with respect to $\lambda$ at $\lambda=1$, we obtain $f(x)$ in the right-hand side. The left-hand side is the directional deivative of $f$ at $x$ along the direction $x$. By Rademacher's theorem, it exists a.e. and is equal to $x \cdot \nabla f(x)$.

$\Leftarrow$ Given $x$ define the scalar function $g(\lambda)=f(\lambda x)$. Then $\lambda g'(\lambda)= \lambda x \nabla f(\lambda x) = g(\lambda)$ a.e.
Since $f$ is locally Lipschitz, $g$ is absolutely continuous. Thus, we have the Caratheodory differential equation $g'(\lambda)=g(\lambda)/\lambda$ with the initial condition $g(1)=f(x)$. The absolutely continuous solution of the equation is given by $g(\lambda)=\lambda f(x)$. QED.

Any comments will be very much appreciated.